# Rescaling a symplectic form and integral cohomology

Tags: homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold. I am trying to understand a procedure which seems so obvious that its implications are omitted in any article I could read. I encountered the following: assume that the cohomology class $[\omega]$ of the symplectic form lies in the image of the natural homomorphism
$$\rho : H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}) \to H^2(M,\mathbb{R}).$$
Then up to rescaling $\omega$, we can assume that it is integral, that is $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$.

### Here are my questions:

1. first of all, I don't understand why $\rho$ could not be an embedding. Does this come from the Universal Coefficient Theorem ?
2. If it is indeed not an embedding, then all I can say is that there exists a closed two form $\tau$ such that $\rho([\rho]) = [\omega]$. Then how could I obtain $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$, even by rescaling the form ?
3. What does $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ mean in terms of values $\omega$ can take on $2$-dimensional submanifolds of $M$ ?
4. a more general question: rescaling a symplectic form seems to change the symplectic structure. Why does this procedure seem so meaningless ?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4):

1) Sure, if you like, you can phrase this in terms of the universal coefficient theorem. We have the natural sequences $$0 \to \text{Ext}^1_{\Bbb Z}(H_{i-1}(X;\Bbb Z), R) \to H^2(X;R) \to \text{Hom}(H_2(X;\Bbb Z), R) \to 0.$$

In the case $R = \Bbb R$, the first term is zero. When $M$ is a compact triangulable space (such as a manifold) and $R = \Bbb Z$, the first term is $H_{i-1}(X;\Bbb Z)_{\text{tors}}$, the subgroup of torsion classes. (See eg [here](http://math.jhu.edu/~jmb/note/torext.pdf), Corollary 21.)

The naturality of this sequence implies that the map $H^2(X;\Bbb Z) \to H^2(X;\Bbb R)$ has kernel equal to $H_{i-1}(X;\Bbb Z)_{\text{tors}} \subset H^2(X;\Bbb Z)$; this is the torsion subgroup of $H^2(X;\Bbb Z)$. (Because $\Bbb R$ is divisible, these kernel elements should not surprise you.) The map $H^2(X;\Bbb Z)/\text{Tors} \to H^2(X;\Bbb R)$ is therefore injective, with domain identified with $\text{Hom}(H_2(X;\Bbb Z), \Bbb Z) \cong \Bbb Z^{b_2}$, and codomain identified with $\text{Hom}(H_2(X;\Bbb Z), \Bbb R) \cong \Bbb R^{b_2}$; the inclusion picks out a lattice in $\Bbb R^{b_2}$, and the induced map $$\left(H^2(X;\Bbb Z)/\text{Tors}\right) \otimes_{\Bbb Z} \Bbb R \to H^2(X;\Bbb R)$$
is an isomorphism.

1b) Notice, however, that this does not say that every symplectic form may be rescaled to be integral: we're asking that a line in $\Bbb R^{b_2}$ intersect some element other than $0$ in $\Bbb Z^{b_2}$. This is a very non-generic situation; it is true for a dense, measure 0 set of lines. That last isomorphism means that I can write every element of $H^2(X;\Bbb R)$ as a finite sum $\sum c_i \omega_i$, where $c_i \in \Bbb R$ and $\omega_i \in H^2(X;\Bbb Z)/\text{Tors}$.

2) A symplectic form lives in $H^2(X;\Bbb R)$. To say it is integral means it is in the lattice defined above, the image of $H^2(X;\Bbb Z) \to H^2(X;\Bbb R)$. This is equivalent to saying that $\int_{\Sigma} \omega \in \Bbb Z$ for every closed surface $\Sigma \subset X$. This is the content of saying we live in $$\text{Hom}(H_2 X, \Bbb Z) \subset \text{Hom}(H_2 X, \Bbb R).$$ You don't end up picking out a particular class in $H^2(X;\Bbb Z)$, but that's okay, that wouldn't be a differential form.

3) See above.

4) It changes the volume of submanifolds but not really any of the other symplectic geometry of $M$, other than by scaling factors. For instance, for fixed almost complex structure $J$, then (maybe after a scaling of $J$, I haven't checked) you expect the same moduli spaces of holomorphic discs, hence the same Gromov-Witten type invariants. It's the silliest thing you could do to a symplectic structure that technically gives you something new.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Allow me to ask you some questions about this. Regarding 1): what does it mean for a homology class to lie in a cohomology group (namely you wrote $H_1(X,\mathbb{Z})_{\text{tor}} \subset H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$) ? Regarding 1b): if I understand well you identify the codomain $H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$ of the injection $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z}) / Tor \to H^2(X,\mathbb{R})$ with $Hom(H_2(X,\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}^{b_2}$ ? In this case, a line would represent a generator of the real second cohomology of $X$, and we ask the line representing $[\omega]$ to intersect the lattice ?

Comment: 1) It's sloppy notation. I'm using the universal coefficient theorem, which identifies the space of torsion elements as a certain Ext-space, which here is that subgroup of $H_1$. 1b) Exactly. In fact, instead of measure 0, I should have said only countably many lines are admissible.

Comment: 1b) By countably many, you mean as many as there are rational lines right ? Also, regarding the notation $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$, consider the case of the existence of a prequantization bundle over a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$. It this existence ensured by the condition $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$, or by $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}) / Tor$ (which is equivalent to saying that it is in the image of the homomorphism) ?

Comment: @BrianT Yes, there are countably many rational lines. I don't know what a prequantization bundle means, but the only place $[\omega]$ lives when $\omega$ is a symplectic form is in de Rham cohomology. So it will never make sense to write $[\omega] \in H^2(M;\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: @BrianT I am reminded from seeing a post that I wrote a while back that "prequantization line bundle" should mean there is a line bundle $L$ with connection $A$ so that the curvature 2-form $F_A = \omega$. Because the curvature form is a constant multiple of the first Chern class ($2\pi$, I think), this is the same thing as saying that your first Chern class takes a certain form in $H^2(M;\Bbb R)$: that it lies in a lattice. But the choice of $(L, A)$ is not unique: one has to account for the flat line bundles, whose curvature is 0.

Comment: Thanks for your comment on prequantizations. I guess that in fact my question is quite general: let $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{R})$ be the cohomology class of an “integral” symplectic form. Then this means that $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}) / Tors$. Let $\sigma \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$ and $\alpha \in Tors$ such that $[\omega] = \sigma + \alpha$. Do we have necessarily $\alpha = 0$ ?

Comment: @BrianT No, that's what the content of 1. was. You can twist by a flat line bundle, which is what these torsion elements of $H^2(X;\Bbb Z)$ represent - line bundles which may be given a connection with zero curvature.

Comment: Oh I see. In fact, for me a prequantization bundle over $(M,\omega)$ is a principal $S^1$-bundle $\pi : (V,\alpha) \to (M,\omega)$, where $\alpha$ is an $S^1$-invariant $1$-form such that $d \alpha = \pi^* \omega$ (it is then a contact form). I am trying to understand why the existence of such a bundle is equivalent to $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z}) / Tors$, and what would a torsion element mean in terms of the form $\alpha$, given that every time I heard someone talking about prequantizations he assumed $[\omega] \in H^2(M,\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: @BrianT I don't know anything about this stuff (I know something about curvature of line bundles, but nothing about 'prequantization') and it's out of the range this answer could reasonably talk about, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any good and reasonable reference about the relation between line bundles, curvatures and torsion in cohomology ?

Comment: @BrianT Not really... there are 3 claims here. 1) Line bundles are classified by their first chern class $c_1(L) \in H^2(M;\Bbb Z)$. 2) If you take a connection on that line bundle, and take the curvature of that connection, you get a class in $H^2(M;\Bbb R)$. This is the image of $c_1(L)$ under the change-of-coefficient isomorphism (up to some scalar factor I forget). 3) Torsion elements of $H^2(M;\Bbb Z)$, therefore, are the Chern classes of line bundles so that $c_1(L) = 0 \in H^2(M;\Bbb R)$. One may then choose a connection on $L$ whose curvature is identically 0.

Comment: Regarding 2), are you saying that any connection has curvature equal to $c_1(L)$, or that one can choose one such that it is true ?

Comment: I am saying that $F_A$ is a closed 2-form whose cohomology class is the de Rham $c_1(L)$. If you pick a particular 2-form in that cohomology class, you may *choose* $A$ so that $F_A$ is that 2-form.